# ¿Por qué obtengo error 400 de la API de Telegram?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, api

Tras haber probado numerosas soluciones y códigos de ajax para llamar a una función de php, sigue apareciéndome el mismo error.

Contexto:

Quiero que me lleguen vía telegram un aviso en caso de que un usuario esté cometiendo una infracción y para eso estoy empleando Ajax y PHP. He probado diversas maneras y nada, siempre da el mismo error, no sé si es porque el código no se puede ejecutar o por qué es, ya que soy nuevo en ajax, javascript y php.

ERRORES QUE DAN:

Consola:

```
jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2 
        
POST http://127.0.0.1/tusc/trie/assets/php/app.php net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED
send @ jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2
ajax @ jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2
mandarMensaje @ load.php:131
```

PHP:

```
[Sun Nov 14 18:44:32.439369 2021] [php:warn] [pid 5392:tid 1816] [client 127.0.0.1:2698] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(https://api.telegram.org/bot2068494256:AAF_t9XFvMXnTO_DvYYks_xDJ_2AgteS5oI/sendMessage?chat_id=1219930456&amp;text=%3Cpre%3E%0D%0A%F0%9F%91%91Supremassy+Hemos+registrado+un+intento+de+vulnerabilidad%2C+informaci%C3%B3n%3A%F0%9F%91%91%0D%0A%0D%0AFraud_Score+%3D+100%0D%0AAI+Check+%3D+%3Cscript+type%3D%22text%2Fjavascript%22%3Econst+value+%3D+localStorage.getItem%28%22ip_f%22%29%3B+%3C%2Fscript%3E++%0D%0A%0D%0A%F0%9F%92%AFHAIL+SUPREMASSY%F0%9F%92%AF%0D%0A%3C%2Fpre%3E&amp;parse_mode=HTML): Failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\n in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\tusc\\trie\\assets\\php\\app.php on line 81, referer: http://127.0.0.1/tusc/trie/load.php
```

CÓDIGOS PHP Y AJAX

AJAX:

```
 $.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "./assets/php/app.php",
data: { badip: "El fego"}
}).done(function( msg ) {
//console.log( "Los datos que se recibieron: " + msg );
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php 
$ip = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP'] : $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$key = ''; //omitida por privacidad
$user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; 
$user_language = $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'];

// Set the strictness for this query. (0 (least strict) - 3 (most strict))
$strictness = 1;

// You may want to allow public access points like coffee shops, schools, corporations, etc...
$allow_public_access_points = 'true';

// Reduce scoring penalties for mixed quality IP addresses shared by good and bad users.
$lighter_penalties = 'false';

// Create parameters array.
$parameters = array(
    'user_agent' => $user_agent,
    'user_language' => $user_language,
    'strictness' => $strictness,
    'allow_public_access_points' => $allow_public_access_points,
    'lighter_penalties' => $lighter_penalties,
    
);

/* User & Transaction Scoring
* Score additional information from a user, order, or transaction for risk analysis
* Please see the documentation and example code to include this feature in your scoring:
* https://www.ipqualityscore.com/documentation/proxy-detection/transaction-scoring
* This feature requires a Premium plan or greater
*/

// Format Parameters
$formatted_parameters = http_build_query($parameters);

// Create API URL
$url = sprintf(
    'https://www.ipqualityscore.com/api/json/ip/%s/%s?%s', 
    $key,
    $ip,
    $formatted_parameters
);

// Fetch The Result
$timeout = 5;

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);

$json = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

// Decode the result into an array.
$result = json_decode($json, true);

  

include 'config.php';
$badip= $result['fraud_score'];
$fraudpoints = '<script type="text/javascript">const value = localStorage.getItem("ip_f"); </script>  ';

$content_login = '<pre>
Supremassy Hemos registrado un intento de vulnerabilidad, información:

Fraud_Score = '.$badip.'
AI Check = '.$fraudpoints.'

HAIL SUPREMASSY
</pre>';

if ($telegram_active === 1) {

  foreach ($chats_id as $chat_id) {
    file_get_contents("https://api.telegram.org/bot$token/sendMessage?chat_id=$chat_id&text=" . urlencode($content_login)."&parse_mode=HTML" );}}
```

Comment: Te da un error 400, eso es que estás enviando algo mal. Revisa que lo que envías es exactamente lo que esperan recibir. Es posible que tu variable `$token` no empiece por /?? Porque parece que te falta una barra ahí: `bot$token` en la llamada a `file_get_contents`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mira el error PHP, te informa de una respuesta 400 a tu petición a api.telegram.org, así que el problema está ahí. Como dice Benito-B, algo estarás enviando mal, si te responde código 400. Y efectivamente parece que te falta una / entre bot y $token.

```
file_get_contents("https://api.telegram.org/bot/$token/sendMessage?.......
```

Comment: Holaa, se me olvidó cerrar la pregunta pero sí, fue un error de envío de data que ya he solucionado, gracias a ambos!